# an android data base problem

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jdbc

When i am calling the my already created data base in SQ lite.It giving the Run time Exception that data base is calling recursively.but every time the data base use  is over i closed it.
what is going wrong with it?i am using eclipse and developing program in android.

i creating the object of helper class(In which i created the database).and and then
using `SQliteDatabase db=hc.getWritebleDatabase();`
Exception is in the above line

```
hc=helperclass object
```

answer me..because on Google i didn't get any related answer.

code getting Exception:::
i have already a data base class named HelperClass .its had table named New_User

```
public void check_pass()
{
boolean flag=true;
private HelperClass hc = new HelperClass(this);
SQLiteDatabase db;  
try{ db=hc.getWritableDatabase();}

catch(Exception ex)
         {
             Toast.makeText(this,""+ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    cur=db.query("New_User",null,null,null,null,null,null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
  do{
   if(cur.getString(0).equalsIgnoreCase(edittext_name.getText().toString())&&cur.getString(3).equals(edittext_pass.getText().toString())){
    flag=false;

    //dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Please wait for few seconds...", true);
    //dialog.setCancelable(true); 
    //dialog.show();
    Intent intent1=new Intent(this,Friends.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
     }
  cur.moveToNext();
   }  while(cur.moveToNext());
    if(flag==true){
       Toast.makeText(this,"Incorecct user name or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    }
```

data base Creation:

```
public class HelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public final static String Db_name="employee.db";
    protected final static int Db_version=1;
    protected final static String Ename="Ename";
    protected final static String Email="Email";
    protected final static String Epass="Epass";
    protected final static String Eabout="Eabout";
    protected final static String Egender="Egender";
    protected final static String Ehob1="Ehob1";
    protected final static String Ehob2="Ehob2";
    protected final static String Ehob3="Ehob3";
    protected final static String Ehob4="Ehob4";


    public HelperClass(Context context){   
    super(context,Db_name,null,Db_version);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db1){
        db1=this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql= "CREATE TABLE New_User("+Ename +" text not null," +
        ""+ Egender +" text not null," +
        ""+ Email +" text not null primary key," +
        "" +Epass+" text not null,"+
        ""+ Eabout +" text not null,"+
        ""+ Ehob1 +" text,"+ Ehob2 +" text,"+ Ehob3 +" text,"+ Ehob4 +" text);";
       db1.execSQL(sql);

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the exception details that logcat provides and the method that the exception is occurring in?

Comment: 04-12 17:04:55.009: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
 This is the exception showing in my log cat

Comment: plz Mr Corey Sunwold answer me if you have idea about this

Comment: Could you please post the full code that the exception is occurring in? It is hard to see what is going wrong without seeing exactly what it is doing.

Comment: ok guys..i got the solution.actually i am using the getWritableDatabase() in on create so every time i try to open its already opened and gave the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
db1=this.getWritableDatabase();
```

So your database onCreate method should be:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db1){
    String sql= "CREATE TABLE New_User("+Ename +" text not null," +
    ""+ Egender +" text not null," +
    ""+ Email +" text not null primary key," +
    "" +Epass+" text not null,"+
    ""+ Eabout +" text not null,"+
    ""+ Ehob1 +" text,"+ Ehob2 +" text,"+ Ehob3 +" text,"+ Ehob4 +" text);";
   db1.execSQL(sql);
}
```

Comment: yes..this was the problem..i got the solution by checking again.Thank you for ur support too

Comment: If possible please either post your solution and mark it as the answer, or mark this as the answer if it solved your issue. SO doesn't like having lots of "unanswered" questions floating around.

Answer (score 0):

Close after use of data base object over
    **strong text**SQLiteDataBase.close();